# How to interact with Akka Actors via Akka HTTP (Java)

Tags: akka-http, akka-actor

### Topic

I would like to **interact with an Akka Actor via Akka HTTP**. The idea is to have a system where a HTTP client calls an Akka HTTP server method, which handles the request to an Akka Actor. The actor processes the message and responds back to the caller (Akka HTTP), which answers to the HTTP client.
I managed to do as described above, but I think I am not doing it correctly since my implementation seems blocking.

I explain better: if I make many concurrent HTTP requests, I see that Akka HTTP "makes a queue", thus waiting for the actor to process a request before sending it the following.

What I would like to obtain instead is that **the Akka HTTP server forwards the requests coming from HTTP clients immediately to the target akka actor, without waiting for the actor to end the elaboration.**
I would like to use the actor mailbox-capacity parameter to determine how big is the message queue and reject messages if they are too many.

Thus I would need a way to have Akka HTTP wait asynchrounsly for the actor response.

I know that the mailbox-capacity is working correctly because If I instead make many requests to my actor using a simple **actor2.tell("Prova1", system.deadLetters())** (just for testing), requests exceeding the mailbox size are correctly rejected.

### References

In order test my system I created a simple configuration following the minimal examples provided by akka documentation.
This for akka http:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/index.html#minimal-example

and the following for creating my actor:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#creating-actors

### My code

The first thing I did was to create a system with one actor (actor1) configure akka HTTP as follows:

```
public class TestActor {

    private static ActorSystem system;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        String httpBindAddress = "0.0.0.0";
        int httpPort = 8086;        
        system = ActorSystem.create("deupnp");
        ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);      
        Http http = Http.get(system);
        AllDirectives app = new AllDirectives() {           
        };

        Route routeActor =  app.get(() ->
        app.pathPrefix("mysuburl", () -> 
        app.pathPrefix(akka.http.javadsl.unmarshalling.StringUnmarshallers.STRING, actor -> 
        app.path(akka.http.javadsl.unmarshalling.StringUnmarshallers.STRING, message -> 
        app.onSuccess(() -> 
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> actorFunctionCall(actor, message)), response -> 
        app.complete(StatusCodes.get(200), response))))));

        Flow<HttpRequest, HttpResponse, NotUsed> routeFlow = app.route(routeActor).flow(system, materializer);
        CompletionStage<ServerBinding> binding = http.bindAndHandle(routeFlow, ConnectHttp.toHost(httpBindAddress, httpPort), materializer);

        // create system with one actor
        ActorRef actor1 = system.actorOf(Props.create(ActorTest.class,"actor1").withMailbox("my-mailbox"),"actor1");    
    }

    private static String actorFunctionCall(String actor, String message)
    {
        try {
            Inbox inbox = Inbox.create(system);
            system.actorSelection("user/"+actor).tell(message, inbox.getRef());
            String response  = (String) inbox.receive(Duration.create(20000, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //return new ResponseMessage(204,"Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

where my ActorTest is the following:

```
public class ActorTest extends AbstractActor {

    private String myName = ""; 

    public ActorTest(String nome){
        this.myName = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public void preStart()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {        
        return receiveBuilder()
            .match(String.class, 
                message -> {
                Thread.sleep(5000l);
                System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + " >> " + myName + " >> " + message);
            })
            .matchAny(mex->{
                System.out.println("Error");
            })
            .build();
    }   
}
```

my application.conf is very simple:

```
akka
{
    stdout-loglevel = "DEBUG"
    loglevel = "DEBUG"
    actor {
        default-dispatcher {
            throughput = 10
        }
    }
}

my-mailbox {
    mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.NonBlockingBoundedMailbox"
    mailbox-capacity = 1
}
```

### Expected results

As you can see, with **mailbox-capacity = 1** I would expect that, 
if I make more than 1 concurrent requests, only one is processed and the rest is discarded.

I think the code above is not correct for what I want to obtain, since I am using Akka HTTP routing in order to receive HTTP requests on http://127.0.0.1/mysuburl/actor1/my_msg and then use **Inbox** to send message to the actor and wait for the response.

So my question is: which is the correct way to link my Akka HTTP request to my Akka Actor actor 1 in an asynchronous way?

Please let me know if you need further details.

#### Note

I even read the following article:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/handling-blocking-operations-in-akka-http-routes.html

which explains how to create a finite number of threads in order to deal with multiple blocking requests, but I think this only "mitigates" the effects of my code, which is blocking, but must be written in a way which is not blocking.